# "Sound argument" in Portuguese

Tags: vocabulário, significado-em-contexto

I have in Portuguese contexts seen the terms "bom", "sólido" and "coesivo" used for arguments which are valid and have true arguments. Is there a preferable or recommended use?

How can I translate "sound argument" in Portuguese?

Comment: "cohesive"? What do you mean? Can you replace that with a Portuguese word?

Comment: I think the suggestion was coesão for soundness and coesivo for sound.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm surprised no one else said it:

**"Sound argument"** translated to the letter is: **"Argumento São"**.

**"São"** is  [homonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) with other words, it can mean "sound", "sain", "saint" or the 3rd person plural present indicative of the verb "to be", [described in the dictionary](https://dicionario.priberam.org/s%C3%A3o). Having its root in the latin word *"sanctus"* one can say the word "são" carries a mystical potential...

Because **"São"** enjoys such wide semantic, and its homonyms are of frequent use, other synonyms with stricter sense are usually preferred instead. (That is why you've seen other terms being employed). I wouldn't say the use of the word for that end is uncommon, rather that it has plentiful alternative synonyms.

Within mathematical logic, the property of "soundness" is frequently translated as "correção". As indicated [in this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140705/what-does-it-mean-to-say-an-algorithm-is-sound-and-complete).

**EDIT:** Regarding the translation in the domain of engineering/mathematics I leave a quote from a thesis published in the university of São Paulo. [Available here.](https://teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/3/3141/tde-10012008-094436/publico/Luiz_Carvalheira_Dissertacao_v20070925_Revisada_Final.pdf)
[image: correção]

**EDIT nº2:** Regarding prevalence on the use of "são" as an adjective together with the word "argumentos". [Thesis from Universidade Federal Fluminense.](https://www.historia.uff.br/stricto/td/2019.pdf)

[image]

**EDIT nº3:** Regarding, again, the translation of soundness as validity in mathematics, the problem is both in English and Portuguese, soundness and validity are different concepts, and thus require different words.

[**Validity:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic))
[image]

[**Soundness:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness)
[image]

Comment: Who would say that in Portuguese? Sound body is corpo são, but not a sound argument. Translated to the letter? You mean literally. soundness in math is validez.

Comment: Olá @Lambie, é bom voltar ver-te por aqui. O problema de pesquisar "argumento são" no google é as ocorrências que usam "são" como verbo, ofuscam as ocorrências de "argumento são" com o útlimo sendo adjectivo. No entanto, por experiência, li o dito uso de "são" muitas vezes em livros com frequência decrescente a partir da laicização do Estado (não é por acaso). O adjectivo é erudito com conotação ético/moral/teológica. Por comparação, pesquisa "razões sãs" o primeiro hit é Bertrand Russel. Se tentares "sãs opiniões", a forma feminina, faz emergir no google o uso que referi...

Comment: @Lambie quanto ao uso no domínio matemático/computacional basta ver na wikipedia que "soundness" do Inglês é traduzido para "correção" (deixo o link no final deste comentário). Embora isto me suscite dúvidas, tenho a impressão que em Portugal é usado outro termo, sendo o "correção" mais usado no Brasil. Não tenho aqui a documentação para confirmar, a literatura Anglo-Saxónica e Brasileira quase afoga a terminologia técnica Portuguesa no google quando esta difere. Fica o link para a correção: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corre%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: I don't care how wikipedia translates it. Wikipedia is not a translator and I am. The soundness of an argument means the validity of an argument. Mathematical or other. Credo, queria dizer: validade. :)

Comment: @Lambie It's good you're a translator, then you'll know that in writing technical/scientific documents certain words have distinct/differing translations from the common dictionaries (it's the scientific community that imposes those differences in their publications). That's why we have dictionaries of law, dictionaries of sociology, dictionaries of engineering, dictionary of mathematics, and frequently the translation in those specific domains will differ from the commonplace translation. (In this case, the wiki translation is the scientific communities established, prevalent, translation.)

Comment: Many of the Portuguese pages have half-baked translations from the English. Se fala em validade de um argumento, em computação e em (lógica) matemática: https://www.pucsp.br/~logica/Argumento.htm By the way, we say sociology, engineering, mathematics, etc. dictionaries.

Comment: @Lambie I revised my post to reflect that validity and soundness are distinct concepts in mathematics and computational logic, thus they can't be expressed by the same word in either language. (Ohhh, and you corrected my syntax :) )

Comment: Only for logic (mathematical logic) here is the distinction: You have to take a look at the paper: https://rintintin.colorado.edu/~vancecd/phil1440/validity.pdf Soundness: An argument is sound if it meets these two criteria: (1) It is valid.
(2) Its premises are true. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corre%C3%A7%C3%A3o Um argumento é dito correto se e somente se: O argumento é válido
Todas suas premissas são verdadeiras.

Comment: sound argument in mathematical logic = argumento correto na lógica matemática. "São" não funciona. Validade e correção = Validity and soundness

Answer (score 4):

A good translation for "sound" here could be:

- sólido
- bem fundamentado

"Bom" just means "good", so it's quite generic and a bit weak; "coerente" (coherent) also isn't as strong as "sound".

Comment: Thanks! I will in contexts where I use this give the definition, and write "solidez" for soundness.

Answer (score 1):

Um argumento válido:

Portuguese translation of 'sound': Collins Dictionary

> sound [saund] ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. (healthy) saudável ⧫ sadio
> 2. (safe, not damaged) sólido ⧫ completo
> 3. (secure) seguro
> 4. (reliable) confiável
> 5. (sensible) sensato
> 6. (argument, policy) **válido**
> 7. (move) acertado

Comment: Acho que "forte" também merece entrar nessa lista. "Sound money" é moeda forte.

Comment: @Macondo moeda forte = strong currency. sound money não se diz nesse contexto.

Comment: Então como você traduziria "sound money"? Pois numa discussão proposta por economistas, para a tradução de um livro, concluíram que "moeda forte" seria a melhor opção.

Comment: @Macondo Eu nunca usaria "sound money", pessoalmente. https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Sound_money no sentido deles: backed by or pegged to some good or commodity é uma coisa. Outra é isso: Sound money is making a resurgence among the more populist Teabaggers, financial bloggers, and even "serious" Republicans.

Comment: No uso serio deles (antes da crítica, que tem muita validez), eu diria: moeda atrelada por mercadorias [commodities].Segundo Wikipedia, moeda forte não é a ideia. Ë claro que se pode dizer argumento forte, sim.

Comment: @Lambie o caso referido pelo Macondo é da terminologia económica, "moeda fiduciária" seria o contrário de uma "moeda lastreada" (não sei a palavra própria). O que "moeda forte" habitualmente significa em Português não é "sound money", significa uma moeda emitida por uma economia saudável, com um alto câmbio, e baixa inflação. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moeda_fiduci%C3%A1ria